# Google Analytics: Use actual pagename as virtual pagename

Tags: google-analytics, tracking

Need help on these 2 questions:

1. If i am tracking a virtual pageview for my tabs, can i use '#' in my virtual filename? i.e. _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/special/#tab1']);
2. If i use a actual pagename for my virtual pagename, will the results be combined? i.e. there's a page called /special/one and i also do a _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/special/one']);

Anyone?

Thanks

Comment: This would be better being asked on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, you can put anything in your string, as long as you escape single quotes
2. Yes, if they match exactly (case sensitive, trailing slash,...), they will be seen as the same page in GA, and thus combine